# Why doesn't the speed of objects change in the reference frame of center of mass?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws, inertial-frames, collision

We often say that before and after 1-d elastic collision, one objects velocity only changes its direction in the reference frame of their centre of mass.
I can show this algebraically, writing equations all the way down and check that it only multiplies by a minus sign, but It's hard to grasp.
I want to know the explanation in terms of physics concept weighted or physics idea involved.

Please help me.

Comment: You are looking only at the special case where one partner had infinite mass and the collision is perfectly elastic

Comment: please cite a specific example that you have trouble understanding. "we often say" is too vague to answer

Comment: @planetmaker Any general elastic collision has this property. You don't need one of the objects to have infinite mass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The center of mass reference frame applies to elastic collisions.  When applying this frame, a frame velocity is selected that guarantees equal and opposite momenta of the colliding objects before the collision.  Because the collision is elastic, kinetic energy must be conserved.  This requirement means that the speed of the objects after the collision MUST equal the speed of the objects before the collision, and this requirement can only be satisfied if each object keeps its original speed but reverses its direction in the center of mass reference frame.

Comment: I agree with your answer. I could be wrong, but I think the OP is looking at a situation where one of the masses involved in the collision is so much greater than the other, that one  is only able to observe the reversal of the smaller mass at the same velocity as initially, and no motion of the larger mass (e.g., elastic collision of a ball with a brick wall), in apparent violation of conservation of momentum, though in actuality the larger mass does "move".. For all practical purposes, the COM is the location of the larger mass.

Comment: @BobD, in the case of a small mass colliding with a very large mass (e.g., almost infinite mass), the center of mass is as you say, located at the large mass, and the velocity of that mass is effectively zero.  When the velocities of the colliding objects are reversed after the collision, the large mass still has a velocity of zero.

Comment: I agree, but my point is the velocity of the large mass is not zero, just infinitely small since it would equal  $$V=\frac{2mv}{M}$$. I think that may be the point missed by many. Anyway, just thought I'd bring it up. Probably not important.